# Differentiation with basic methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differentiate: $\tan(x°+45°)$.
Please help as answer in book is not matching my answer. I converted degrees into radians.

Comment: this is not what a differential equation is bro

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\tan\left(x \frac{\pi}{180}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

$$
f^{'}(x)=\sec^2\left(x\frac{\pi}{180}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \frac{\pi}{180}$$

1 degree = $$\frac{\pi}{180}$$ radians

Comment: Oh... Then book is wrong..... Thnx btw